# Android Gallery Item Focused?

Tags: java, android, gallery

The default gallery widget only provides events for when items are clicked, but is there any way to tell what item is selected when only dragging the gallery around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haha, solved it myself. Seems that the onItemSelectedListener will work for both clicks and dragging.